# How to build stream expression with StreamFactory

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to build let expression for solr stream but it gives error saying 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid stream expression col(samples,score) - function 'col' is unknown (not mapped to a valid TupleStream)

```
StreamFactory = new StreamFactory().withDefaultZkHost(zookeeper)
        .withFunctionName("search", CloudSolrStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("select", SelectStream.class)
        .withFunctionName("merge", MergeStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("sort", SortStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("tuple", TupStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("rollup", RollupStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("hashJoin", HashJoinStream.class)
        .withFunctionName("count", CountMetric.class) 
        .withFunctionName("facet", FacetStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("sum", SumMetric.class) 
        .withFunctionName("unique", UniqueStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("significantTerms", SignificantTermsStream.class)
        .withFunctionName("stats", StatsStream.class)
        .withFunctionName("innerJoin", InnerJoinStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("issnMerge", IssnMergeStream.class) 
        .withFunctionName("intersect", IntersectStream.class)
        .withFunctionName("boostByEra", BoostBooksByEraExpression.class)
        .withFunctionName("determineRRec", DetermineRepresentativeRecord.class)
        .withFunctionName("plist", ParallelListStream.class)
        .withFunctionName("let", LetStream.class);
```

My expression is as below:

let(samples=search(wc_art,qt="/select",q="al:next AND al:generation",fq="_delete:false",fq="_namespace:default",fl="score,numdocs(),id",rows=10,fq="{!lucene q.op=OR}pa:(medline)",defType=edismax,q.op=AND,sort="score desc"),responses=col(samples,score),summary=describe(responses))

Comment: `col` was added in Solr 7. Which version of Solr are you running on?

Comment: I could fix issue after updating solr library version 7.0 to 7.4

Answer (score 0):

The `col` function was added in Solr 7, so if your Solr installation is older than that the function won't be available. Upgrade to a more recent version.